# TD with [white-space:no-wrap] is not working as expected?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table :

[image]

please look at the right TD.

the yellow div should have its height (mandatory). and I need to vertical align the `checkbox`+`SPAN`

So I put both of them as : `float:left` and played with `margin-top`.

But When I reduce the browser width , the `SPAN` is going down :

[image]

*I already put no-wrap.*

I don't care that the text (td#2 ) will be wrapped I just need that the `check-box` +`span` will be together  - always.
and I can't use a `width` on a wrapper div  cause the `Yes` here is in English but it's a multilanguage site. So i need the text to be fit in as its original length.

What can I do so the both elements wont be wrapped ?

here is the <strike>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oquniq/1/edit)</strike>. [**Here it is**](http://jsbin.com/oquniq/8/edit)

```css
td{
  border:solid 1px green;
}

.myCheck{
  float:left;
  margin-top:16px;
}


.mySpan{
  float:left;
  margin-top:12px;
}
```

```html
<table style='width:100%;' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing tempor incididunt ut labore et 
    </td>
    <td style='white-space:nowrap;'>
      <div style='white-space:nowrap; height:50px;background-color:yellow;float:left;'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='myCheck' />
        <span  class='mySpan'>Yes</span>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the problem :

[image]

In Firefox it does wrap it but in Chrome it does not (which is how it should be).

Comment: Please transfer the code from JSbin to here, so the question will remain open. As is, it lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/oquniq/26/edit

```
<td style='white-space:nowrap;'>
  <label>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <span class='mySpan'>
      Yes
    </span>
  </label>
</td>
```

And use `position:relative` to adjust the text's vertical align

```
.mySpan
{
  position:relative;
  top:-2px;
}
```

Comment: Working as desired without manipulating the html structure. Excellent.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the rule is `nowrap` not `no-wrap`.

Comment: fixed. but the problem remains in Firefox. ( in chrome its ok) http://jsbin.com/oquniq/8/edit

Comment: I don't know how to update jsbin, but it's fixed in FFX if you remove the `float: left` from the span/checkbox

Comment: you can save with ctrl+s and see that the url is different. now paste it.

Comment: but if i remove the Float , I wont be able to play with margin-top etc...

Comment: Why not?  When I removed them it looked fine to me

Comment: try to adjust  the vertical location of the span in FF http://jsbin.com/oquniq/17/edit I didnt suuceed. ( becuase I removed the float as you said)

Comment: Change the span to `display: inline-block` or use padding on the container div.

Comment: this will remove it down http://jsbin.com/oquniq/19/edit ( FF)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24668/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-royi-namir)

Answer (score 0):

The breaking onto a new line is casued by the elements being individually floated left.

Put the checkbox within the `<span>` (or better would be a `<label>` element) and this will fix it. Also it is not required to float the element - you can just make it `display: block;`.

```
<label  class='mySpan'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='myCheck' />
    Yes
</label>
```

Remove `.myCheck` styling and set the `.mySpan` CSS to be:

```
.mySpan{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put a table in that td, so it won' t wrap

```
<td style='white-space:no-wrap;'>

<table style='white-space:no-wrap;height:50px;background-color:yellow;'>

          <tr>
            <td> <label  class='mySpan'>Yes</label></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' class='myCheck' /></td>

          </tr>
<table>

</td>
```

P.S : HTML is semantic , so for a label, use the label element, that's better for the world :)

Comment: yeah i table it is working of course. I was just wondering what should I do in order to fix it. ( and to have full control)

Comment: so i don't understand what's the problem ? you want the label and the input to always be align, right ?